# How to align a single cell in reportlab Table

Tags: python, django, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am Creating a table with [reportlab](/questions/tagged/reportlab), I want to align a single cell (to the right) in the following table:

[image]

I want to align the cell containing "Occupation" to right

This is my code:

```
studentProfileData = [
                ['Application Form No', ''],
                ['Name', userData['studentDetails']["firstName"] + " " +userData['studentDetails']["lastName"]],
                ['Course opted for', userData['courseDetails']["courseOptedFor"]],
                ['Specific Course Name', courseMapping["Name"]],
                ['Category', userData['studentDetails']['caste']],
                ['Religion', userData['studentDetails']['religion']],
                ['Fathers'+ "'" +'s Name', userData['studentDetails']['religion']],
                ['Occupation', userData['studentDetails']['fOccupation']],
                ['Phone No', ""],
                ['Term', ""]
            ]

        colwidths = [3 * inch, 1.5 * inch, inch]

        # Two rows with variable height
        rowheights = [.5*inch] * len(studentProfileData)
        studentProfile = Table(studentProfileData, colwidths, rowheights, hAlign='LEFT')

        studentProfile.setStyle(TableStyle([
                ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, -1), "LEFT"),
                ('FONTSIZE', (0,0), (-1, -1), 13),
            ]))

        parts = [ page1Head, studentProfile]
```

Comment: Do you mean a cell instead of column? As the question says "I want to align the Occupation to right".

Comment: I want to align the text "Occupation" only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to align a single cell in a Reportlab `Table` we need to change the `TableStyle` to the following:

```
TableStyle([
            ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, -1), "LEFT"),
            ('FONTSIZE', (0,0), (-1, -1), 13),
            ('ALIGN', (0, 7), (0, 7), "RIGHT"),
        ])
```

This works because we now tell that cells in the area between `(0,7)` and `(0,7)` should be aligned right, as the only cell in that area is the cell containing `Occupation` only that text is aligned.

An alternative approach is to use a `Paragraph` instead of just a `String` in the table, in that case we can do the alignment with the `Paragraph` as it will fill the complete width of the cell.

**Paragraph Example**

```
pageTextStyleCenter = ParagraphStyle(name="left", alignment=TA_CENTER, fontSize=13, leading=10)

[ Paragraph("Occupation", pageTextStyleCenter) , userData['studentDetails'].get('fOccupation', "-")]
```

Comment: I am used Paragraph to solve the problem, and thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for adding the example, I changed it one thing in it, that is completely unrelated to the styling namely instead of checking whether a dict has a key you can use `dict.get(key, alternative)` to do what you did :)